# How to deal with discrepancy in csv and pandas Df?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, validation, data-preprocessing, exploratory-data-analysis

when i load the dataset on pandas it shows 1,00,000 rows but when i open it on excel it shows 3,00,000 rows ? is there any python code that could help me in dealing with this kind of discrepancy

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('C_data_2.csv')
```

```
# Get the counts of each value in the gender column
counts = df['Gender'].value_counts()

# Find the most common value in the gender column
most_common = counts.index[0]

# Impute missing values in the gender column with the most common value
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].fillna(most_common)

# Replace all instances of "nan" with most_common in the "gender" column
df["Gender"].replace("nan", most_common, inplace=True)
```

Comment: please provide an example of the content of `C_data_2.csv` and a screenshot of what you get in excel

Comment: its a dataset for cars, when i open the contents of C_data_2.csv in excel and choose a column the value of counts is 3,00,000 but when i load it in a pandas dataframe the value becomes 1,14,000, also the datase has many Nan values too @mozway